# How to get the new row order after sort rows in jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have the following grid definition:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#thegrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/ajax/questions/get/" + form_id,
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['id', 'grid_id', 'seq', 'type', 'text'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'field_id', index: 'id', width: 100, editable: false, search: false},
            {name: 'grid_id', index: 'grid_id', width: 50, editable: false, search: false},
            {name: 'field_seq', index: 'seq', width: 45, editable: false, search: false},
            {name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 125, editable: false, search: false},
            {name: 'field_name', index: 'text', width: 585, search: false}
        ],
        autowidth: true,
        rowNum: 200,
        cmTemplate: {width: 300, autoResizable: true},
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        guiStyle: "bootstrap",
        autoResizing: {compact: true, resetWidthOrg: true},
        viewrecords: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortable: true,
        pager: true,
        toppager: true,
        hoverrows: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiPageSelection: false,
        rownumbers: true,
        loadonce: true,
        autoresizeOnLoad: true,
        forceClientSorting: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        prmNames: {id: "field_id"},
        jsonReader: {id: "field_id"},
        localReader: {id: "field_id"},
        navOptions: {edit: false, add: false, search: false, del: false, refresh: true},
        pgbuttons: false,
        pginput: false,
        caption: "Questions",
        height: 100,
        editurl: '/ajax/questions/edit',
        onSelectRow:
            function () {
                // ....
            },
        loadComplete: function () {
            // ...
        }
    })
});
```

With the code above it's possible to sort the rows by dragging them and dropping at some position at the grid.

In order to keep this changes I have a function in the backend that takes a `form_id` (I have this stored at sessionStorage) and an array of `field_id => field_seq` and do some magic at DB level.

Take a look at the following picture which is a  grid that has been loaded for first time:

[image]

Now let's say I am dragging & dropping the colored row (`id: 219110`) into the first row position. That will makes the first row (`id: 219110`) to move one row down (same will happen to all rows after that one) and then the moved row will take the first position. See example below:

before:

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| id     | gri_id | seq |
+--------+--------+-----+
| 219111 |        | 1   |
| ...    |        | ... |
| 219110 |        | 4   |
+--------+--------+-----+
```

after:

```
+--------+--------+-----+
| id     | gri_id | seq |
+--------+--------+-----+
| 219110 |        | 1   |
| 219111 |        | 2   |
| ...    |        | ... |
+--------+--------+-----+
```

I need to build and array with the `id` as the `key` and the `seq` as the value so I can pass this later on to an AJAX backend function which will care about store the new data.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lastSelectedData` parameter of jqGrid to get the items, which users sorted and filtered previously. The old answers: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274864/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41442874/315935) provides the demos, which demonstrates the usage of `lastSelectedData`.

In general, jqGrid contains internally some JavaScript methods, which are used for sorting and filtering of local data. I described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9831125/315935) tricky technique, which works on old jqGrid (i version <=4.7). Already in the first version of "free jqGrid" fork I implemented `lastSelectedData` parameter (see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README48.md#some-demos-which-demonstrates-new-features)), which makes working with the last sorted and filtered local data very easy.

Comment: Oleg, what would be the correct event to use after I reorder the rows? I was looking at [jQgrid Wiki for Events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) and all I can see and that has some sense to me is `onSortCol` but I think is not the right one. The idea is to trigger an AJAX call with the values from `lastSelectedData` as soon as I drag & drop the row at some position.

Comment: @ReynierPM: The goal of `onSortCol` is giving a possibility to **prevent** sorting request. Reordering of the rows with respect of drag & drop means that you used `sortableRows` method, which uses jQuery UI internally. One can use `update` callback of the method to get new order. See demos from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3357770/315935) or [another old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045125/315935) or [the next one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41748340/315935)

Comment: I couldn't make it to work, I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/Lofcv9vm/1/). The test: if I move any row to the first position then I would expected that as the first item on the `lastSelectedData` however I am getting the initial array. Can you take a look and tell me what I am missing?

Comment: @ReynierPM: `lastSelectedData` shows the order of *sorted data* based on sorting criteria (`sortname`, `sortorder`). `sortableRows` allows the user to resort the data of the current page independent on any sorting criteria. One have to use `rowIndex` properties of `rows` to get the order of rows after drag & drop (see the demos from old answers, which references I posted). `lastSelectedData` or `data` will be **not changed**.

Comment: I am not following you, I have read the demos but none seems to reflect what I am looking for

Comment: @ReynierPM: `sortableRows` uses jQuery UI sortable, which "knows" nothing about jqGrid, It allows just resort rows of HTML table in any order, which the user like. [the ole demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortaleRows1.htm) shows that `ui.item[0]` is DOM of `<tr>`, which has `rowIndex` property (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tablerow.asp), for example), like all other rows available via [tableDom.rows](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) property. It allows to get new order of rows (rowids) after drag & drop. See the source code of the demo.

Comment: so if I am following you know this is tricky and can't be done from within jQgrid without involve what you've show me before. Having said that, because the example is using thr `rowId` do we have such value in `data` or `lastSelectedData`? My idea is to get the original data array and then having this `rowIndex` loop over the elements and find the one I am dragging & dropping so I can reorder the elements with the new position, I am not seeing any other way to achieve this :(

Comment: @ReynierPM: Everything is easy too, but you have to use another technique. I'm now in business trip in Switzerland and I'm the whole time at one customer. Thus I just have almost no time for stackoverflow. $("#test")[0] is DOM of table and `$("#test")[0].rows[i]` (index 0 - hidden row without data, but starting with index 1 - the rows with data) are the rows (`<tr>` elements) with properties like `id` and `rowIndex`. `update: function (ev, ui) {...}` provide `ui.item[0]`, which is also DOM of `<tr>`. You can use `ui.item[0].rowIndex` to know new position if `$("#test")[0].rows` array.

Comment: great I think I make it to work see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/Lofcv9vm/2/). I need to build a `key => value` pair using the `seq` column, how do I get that value as well?